# Cloudinary with Carrierwave not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud, carrierwave, cloudinary

I have got a problem with importing Cloudinary::CarrierWave in my Rails application. I have got this error on line with import (include Cloudinary::CarrierWave unless Rails.env.test?)

> undefined method `cache_storage' for AvatarUploader:Class Did you mean? cache_dir

What might be the problem here?

My avatar uploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave unless Rails.env.test?

  process :convert => 'png'
  process :tags => ['post_picture']
  process :custom_crop

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :postgresql_table

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  #def store_dir
  #  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  #end

  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default-avatar.png")
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :eager => true
    #process crop: :avatar
    resize_to_limit(300,300)
    cloudinary_transformation :quality => 80, :gravity => :face
  end

  version :mini do
    process :eager => true
    #process crop: :avatar
    resize_to_limit(40,40)
    cloudinary_transformation :quality => 80, :gravity => :face
  end

  def public_id
    return model.full_name
  end

  def custom_crop
    return :x => model.crop_x, :y => model.crop_y,
        :width => model.crop_width, :height => model.crop_height, :crop => :crop
  end
end
```

My user.rb

```
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  crop_uploaded :avatar
```

in application.js

```
//= require cloudinary/jquery.cloudinary
```

in application.html.haml

```
= cloudinary_js_config
```

in environment.rb

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
```

cloudinary.yml

```
#CLOUDINARY_URL: "myurl"

development:
  cloud_name: mycloud
  api_key: 'xxxx'
  api_secret: xxxx
#  enhance_image_tag: true
#  static_file_support: false
production:
  cloud_name: mycloud
  api_key: 'xxxx'
  api_secret: xxxx
#  enhance_image_tag: true
#  static_file_support: true
test:
  cloud_name: mycloud
  api_key: 'xxxx'
  api_secret: xxxx
#  enhance_image_tag: true
#  static_file_support: false
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave', '0.10.0'
#gem "carrierwave-postgresql-table"
gem 'carrierwave-crop', '0.1.2'
gem 'cloudinary
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using this really old version of the Carrierwave gem - could you try updating to a newer version?

Comment: I updated carrierwave gem, but it did not help

Comment: What is the version of Carrierwave you're using and also the Cloudinary gem?

Comment: carrierwave (0.11.2) and cloudinary (1.16.1)

Comment: 0.11.2 of Carrierwave doesn't have cache_storage. Could you update to the latest stable version 2.1.0?

Comment: It works after update carrierwave to version 2.1.0, but I have got a problem with carrierwave-crop now :( carrierwave crop need carrierwave < 0.11.0, >= 0.8.0